# Could not import app.models in view file

Tags: python, django, django-models, import

First django app and am having a bit of trouble my project is laid out like this

```
MyProject
  -dinners (python package, my app)
    -views (python package)
      __init__.py
      dinners.py(conflict was here... why didn't I add this to the q.. sigh)
      general.py
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
  -Standard django project boilerplate
```

In my /views/general.py file it looks like this:

```
import os
import re
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context,loader
from dinners.models import Dinner

def home(request):
    first_page_dinners = Dinner.objects.all().order_by('-created_at')[:5]
    t = loader.get_template('general/home.html')
    c = Context({
        'dinners':first_page_dinners,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(Context()))
```

And in my urls.py file I have this regular expression to map to this view

```
url(r'^/*$','dinners.views.general.home', name="home")
```

However when I try to hit the home page I get this error:
Could not import dinners.views.general. Error was: No module named models

Removing the dinners.models import at the top of general.py (plus all of the model specific code) removes the error. Am I somehow importing incorrectly into the view file? Naturally I need to be able to access my models from within the view...

Thanks

UPDATE: answer I had a file dinners.py within the -views package that was conflicting

Comment: Is there any `__init__.py` file under `dinners/views/`?

Comment: Remove the * from the URL pattern (it has nothing to do with your error, but it's a good practice). Just leave r'^' if you want to match any url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a `__init__.py` file in "dinners" and "views" folder to make those valid packages.

**EDIT:**

Also, remove that views.py file, that will create conflict with the package.

Comment: I have those file (sorry for not including).. will update post with correct file structure

Comment: uhm, sorry for that brother, I thought you missed it and that might be  making conflicts.

Comment: no worries, that was a good catch. I'm getting import errors in the python shell as well not a great start

Comment: Do you have a views.py file too? I mean, a views package and a views.py file inside "dinners" package?

Comment: Yeah. I have a views.py inside 'dinners' package, and a views package (which is located inside dinners package)

Comment: Still nothing.. Also I can no longer access the /admin section of the site (using django built in admin) could this be some weird circular reference?

Comment: Ah!!! Turns out I had another file dinners.py within the views package that was giving it a conflict... I think next time I shouldn't leave anything out. I'm going to give you credit for this because you helped a lot :)

Comment: Haha, thanks. Hope you worked that out. Python can be very annoying with it's path and all that stuff